# Find: why the regex with egrep doesn't work?

Tags: find, regular-expression

The first example without pipe return empty.

```
find /tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/ -regextype posix-egrep -regex [A-Z][A-Z]$
```

The second return what I want, all files with capitalized letters, why the find command return nothing?

```
find /tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/ |egrep [A-Z][A-Z]$ 
/tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
/tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
/tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/.git/logs/HEAD
/tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/.git/HEAD
/tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/NEWS
/tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/COPYRIGHT
/tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/AUTHORS
/tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/TODO
/tmp/txz/httperf/httperf-20210403git/src/lib/README
```

I have tried also posix-extended and posix-basic for regex-type, but return empty.

Comment: You should always quote the argument to `-regex` and `-name`, otherwise the shell might expand them before `find` sees them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As POSIX `find` does not specify `-regex`, I assume GNU `find`.

> Test: `-regex expr`
> Test: `-iregex expr`
> True if the entire file name matches regular expression `expr`. **This is a match on the whole path, not a search.** […]

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html#Full-Name-Patterns), emphasis mine)</sup>

You should use `-regex '.*[A-Z][A-Z]'`. Note the expression is single-quoted to prevent expansion by the shell.

Comment: or something like `-regex '.*/[A-Z]+$'`, to match `.../HEAD`, but not `.../fooBAR`